# Google App Engine - low performance with concurrent requests

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, concurrency

I have made an experiment with Google App Engine.
I've added execution time measurements to my Python 3 web service . They are measuring real time that passed during code execution, not CPU time (using `time.time()`).
One of the measurements is taking whole python function code execution: measurement stars as the first line of the function and is ended right before returning the result.
For a simple test input, timing is as expected: it took around 0.7 seconds to perform all function operations. As can be seen in logs.
[image]

Presented times are similar regardless if data is requested sequentially by one thread or in parallel by 16 threads. I am using JMeter for simulating the load.
The more interesting part is the overall request time.
When queried by one thread sequentially response time is similar to the time taken by code execution:
[image]

But for some reason, when service is queried in parallel by 16 threads overall response time grows to 11 seconds:
[image]

I am surprised by this behavior.
I checked the resources used by service. In the peak moment CPU was used by 40% and RAM usage was under 600 MB.

Here is the `app.yaml` configuration for this service:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
service: my_service_name
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 240 --limit-request-line 0

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 10
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.8

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2
```

When I am starting webservice locally on my laptop I am getting the same average response time regardless of the number of concurrent threads.
Any tips or hints how to configure this to work efficient for the parallel requests highly appreciated.

Comment: By default, GAE standard provides the `threadsafe` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#threadsafe), when set to true, this provides request concurrency. However, this doesn't work for GAE flex since you need to manage the requests on your own. How are you handling your concurrent requests in your GAE flex? Perhaps you could try to change your Gunicorn configuration and tweak the number of workers that handle the requests. More information can be found in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#workers).

Comment: You may also take a look at [Python's 3 threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

GAE flex is much slower to scale than GAE standard.  If you need to scale quickly, see if GAE standard can work for you.

For how long did you run the parallel test?  I expect that if you run it for a sufficient length of time (5-15 minutes), then your app will scale up and the response time will be back below 1 second.

Comment: I let tests run for 15 minutes. Latency had not changed. GAE did not scaled, as the CPU usage was under 20%.

Comment: @MichałHerman, maybe share more details of your parallel tests.  For each of your 16 threads, how frequently are they POSTing?  Do you do another POST as soon as the previous one returns?  When you runs this for 15 minutes, how many instances are active?  Maybe add a graph showing how your instances are scaling up?